# clearing the cache from jQuery's data-dom-cache with button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a search page which has data-dom-cache in the page. So if the user happens to go back to the search page, his/her results are saved. However, after the user goes through the whole process, he/she can choose to press the button "Search Again" to start over again. This time the page needs to  reset to the default stage and not have the saved results.

Is there any way I can do this in jQuery? I'm also using MVC 4 RC, so if theres any way to fix that in the controller, I'd be happy to hear it. I tried using

```
HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/Views/Booking/Index.cshtml");
```

but I wasn't able to get it to work. Thanks for your help.